# Why doesn't Icon(Icons.add) give me a warning when I turn on prefer_const_constructors in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I have [`prefer_const_constructors` in `analysis_options.yaml`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_const_constructors.html), it will warn me when I can use const constructors but I don't.

For example:

```dart
class A {
  const A();
}

void accessA() {
  A a = A();
}
```

This will give me a warning.

But, when I use `Icon(Icons.add)` instead of `const Icon(Icons.add)` in Flutter code, I don't see any warnings. Why?

Comment: You might want to file an issue as this really seems quite odd. Otherwise, I might consider starting a bounty on this question. What is even weirder is that it does warn me for some icons but not for all of them. `Icon(Icons.send)` does get detected but others do not. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot thanks a lot for the reply. I tried `Icon(Icons.send)`, but it doesn't warn me at all. Is that something to do with the analyzer cache files? If you think this is a bug, can you please file it and link the bug here? You are more professional than me. I am even not sure which repo is responsible for dart analyzer. :) Thanks.

Comment: I [filed an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/1592).

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot thank you very much for the work. I have thumbed up and subscribed that issue. :)